# "Poison damage" affix: is it worh it?

Tags: the-mighty-quest-for-epic-loot

I found an item with this affix, but it greatly reduces my overall DPS (-74) while it adds 16 poison damage, ridiculously boosting my damage range (+1).

Is it worth it ?  I doubt it, but perhaps the poison damage has some properties that make it interesting (like there's no "Poison armor" stat, perhaps) ?

[image: Poison damage]